# What is the difference between ViewData, ViewBag and TempData?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm using .net mvc 4.0 for my new project. I want to know What is the difference between ViewData, ViewBag and TempData?

I tried searching on net but didn't find any well document material.

Comment: read this http://rachelappel.com/when-to-use-viewbag-viewdata-or-tempdata-in-asp.net-mvc-3-applications

Comment: Searching _What is the difference between ViewData, ViewBag and TempData?_ only gave me 6000 hits!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [Top 10 ASP.NET MVC Interview Questions](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/653746/Top-ASP-NET-MVC-Interview-Questions),

> In order to pass data from controller to view and in next subsequent
>   request, ASP.NET MVC framework provides different options i.e.,
>   ViewData, ViewBag and TempData.
>
> Both ViewBag and ViewData are used to communicate between controller
>   and corresponding view. But this communication is only for server
>   call, it becomes null if redirect occurs. So, in short, it's a
>   mechanism to maintain state between controller and corresponding view.
>
> ViewData is a dictionary object while ViewBag is a dynamic property (a
>   new C# 4.0 feature). ViewData being a dictionary object is accessible
>   using strings as keys and also requires typecasting for complex types.
>   On the other hand, ViewBag doesn't have typecasting and null checks.
>
> TempData is also a dictionary object that stays for the time of an
>   HTTP Request. So, Tempdata can be used to maintain data between
>   redirects, i.e., from one controller to the other controller.

Comment: Don't you think you should clarify that you copied this from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/653746/Top-ASP-NET-MVC-Interview-Questions)? There is nothing wrong on referencing other sites but original author should get credit

Comment: You are also answering an obvious duplicate.

Comment: Yes, I should Have included the reference too... :)

Comment: When you copy something from somewhere else, **you must include a link to the original, and quote-format the copied text**, otherwise it looks like plagiarism.